# C++ Naming Convention

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

What is the widely accepted naming convention for c++ ? (functions, classes, parameters, local variables, namespaces, etc)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think there is a "widely accepted" naming convention in C++. [Stroustrup](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/)'s books and papers generally has the following coding style:

```
class Shape {
public: // interface to users of Shapes
    virtual void draw() const;
    virtual void rotate(int degrees);
    // ...
protected:  // common data (for implementers of Shapes)
    Point center;
    Color col;
    // ...
};
```

You also may want to look at popular style guides like [The Google C++ Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml).

Comment: maybe i'm having a silly moment, but i see no reason for this to deserve a down-vote. explanation from the down-voter? if it's just a personal preference for a particular style, Stroustrup's style isn't any worse than the other two recommendations.

Comment: is the class name supposed to be first letter uppercase like in java? ive seen a lot of c++ classes have lower case first letter

Answer (score 1):

Coding convention is up to you, consistency is what is important. For my own projects, I use [Google's coding style](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html).

Stay away from hungarian notation.

Comment: Unless your projects consist of maintaining huge C++-as-C code bases, you really shouldn't use that coding style. Modern C++ cringes at it.

Comment: @GManNickG - it's been a while.. but could you add more details on why Google convention is bad for modern c++?

Comment: @Andrii: There are probably more elaborated reasons elsewhere, but essentially it boils down to using C++ as C with classes.

Answer (score 1):

It depends somewhat on the platform. For example, MFC applications have a certain naming style (which I happen to follow), others use a different style.

Sort of like different C++ "cultures".